# How do I set size of a Python xray 2Dplot?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Is there any parameter that I could use on this line of code

```
ds.sel(time = '2015-12-16T02:00:00').t2m.plot()
```

to change plot size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, just pass the axis handle into the plot method:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 4))

ds.sel(time='2015-12-16T02:00:00').t2m.plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: You can also set the default figure size with `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (3, 4)`.